# OO PHP | Properly Passing POST Paramaters

Tags: php, oop, post, methods, authentication

I am relatively new to OO PHP and I am trying to create a login class.
The issue I am having is that I want to pass the POST values username and password to my class but I cannot establish a decent way of doing so.

below is a snippet of my class

```
class PortalLogin{
    private $username;
    private $password;

    function __construct(){
        //I connect to DB here
    }

    function login($username, $password){
        //error check the paramaters here
        //then I can run the query
    }

    function __destruct(){
        //I disconnect from DB here
    }
}
```

Above is a breakdown of the class I am creating below is how i plan to execute it (my main issue at the moment).

```
$login = new PortalLogin();

if(isset($_POST['username'])){

    if(isset($_POST['password'])){

        $login->login($_POST[username],$_POST[password]);

    } else {

        //throw error

    }

} else {

    //throw error

}
```

I really do not like the construction of the code above it seems to messy to be doing so much outside of my class. how can I pass the POST information to the class and execute the checks there? I am worrying that if I pass the POST information to the class and one of the POSTS contains nothing it will error.

Comment: It's [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP), BTW!

Comment: Seems like proper OO to me. Except you should inject the already established DB connection in the constructor of `PortalLogin` instead of doing the whole connection in the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you got a problem with the syntax of post..

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){

 $login->login($_POST['username'],$_POST['password']);

}
```

use AND.. so if both username and password exist then call the login function()

Comment: Have to agree there... by not including the quotes around the attribute names, a notice will be generated.

Comment: yeah.. I also advice you to sanitize the inputs.. =) or else some users can bypass your login..

Comment: Let's hope he uses prepared statements.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER yes.. otherwise use mysql_real_escape_string()... mysql_* function is deprecated though..

Comment: this definatly seems better in terms of efficiency but how do i detect if the user has only entered their username and clicked submit? because then i will want an error. because if I put an else statement on this then it would run the error every time.

Comment: if he only entered username... then just put some error message.. like invalid username or password!..... just put nested if...to validate if the inputs is not equal = ""/null... mysqli has prepared statements too.. =) happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure where OOP comes in to this, but if you were going the object-oriented route you would have a class that represents a request from which you could grab POST data from:

```
$username = $request->post('username');
$password = $request->post('password');
```

Your `post()` method could return a default value (`null`) if the variable didn’t exist in the POST data.

You could then have a class that checks your user based on these variables:

```
$auth = new AuthService($dbConnection);

if ($auth->checkCredentials($username, $password)) {
    // Valid user
} else {
    $error = $auth->getLastError();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I might be in the minority with suggesting this, but I favour static methods for things like this. `PortalLogin` represents an action rather than data

```
class PortalLogin
{
    /**
     * Attempt login
     * @param string $username
     * @param string $password
     */
    public static function login ($username, $password)
    {
        // do your login stuff
    }
}
```

Then to use you would do this:

```
if (isset($_POST['username']
    && !empty($_POST['username']
    && isset($_POST['password']
    && !empty($_POST['password']
) {
    PortalLogin::login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
}
```

Even better OO would be to have the username/password checking baked into the `User` class. (Maybe `User::checkLoginCredentials($u, $p); // boolean yup/nope`)

Comment: “Even better OO would be to have some of this baked into the User class.” I’d disagree. That’s mixing concerns.

Comment: @MartinBean What I meant was that you'd mix the ability to authenticate a user into the `User` class. What you'd do then is take the username/password, authenticate with the `User` class and then proceed to set the session etc.

Comment: I know exactly what you meant, and it’s still mixing concerns. Authentication shouldn’t be added to the User class. What happens if the OP then needs to authenticate a different type of user?

Comment: @MartinBean good point, maybe best to split it off into a separate class, but still in the same namespace to keep them nominally associated.

Answer (score -2):

You can use error suppression, like this:

```
$login->login(@$_POST['username'], @$_POST['password']);
```

If one or both values are not present in the $_POST variable, there won't be an error when calling the method, so you can do the error handling inside your class method.

For more info, check:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Edit:
Another option is to do this:

```
$login->login((isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : null), (isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : null));
```

Comment: Never use error suppression. Because it makes debugging your code difficult as hell and slows down the whole thing.

Comment: The question here is to check if the values are set inside the class, so you are sure it will be checked.

Comment: You should not check them inside the method but do it like it's done in the question: check them before passing them into the method. Because the method should do what it's named: try to login. Not check input parameters if they are set or not.

Comment: You really should be doing both checking in the calling code and inside the class, with the class throwing an exception if it doesn't pass.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER but I agree, if you need to resort to using `@` error suppression, you need to rethink your approach.